# from collections import MutableMapping, namedtuple ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections'

Tags: python, python-3.10

`from pymongo import MongoClient`

## I use the mongoDB to store my data, python version 3.10 , mongoDB the latest. But I kept getting the error:

`from collections import MutableMapping, namedtuple ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections'

## I tried to add

`from collections.abc import MutableMapping`

## But always not worked

I tried to update the python to the verion 3.11 by creating another virtual environment, it worked anyway.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMDjr.png)

Then I exit the current working terminal in pycharm， and restart it. and switch to the new venvn virtual environment. But have to install packages again, like scrapy, pymongo, "pymongo[srv]" etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please refrain from using irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

This should work; check your virtual environment:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
```

Link : https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping